# Convert Syntax on Objective C Callback to Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have got an Objective C Framework I am working with and am having a little trouble figuring out the syntax for a callback.

```
typedef void (^PadlocScanScanCallback)(PadlocScanCodeType scanType, NSString *scanData);

@property (nonatomic, strong) PadlocScanScanCallback scanCallback;
```

Figure it would be something like this, but I keep getting an error.

```
config.scanCallback = { (scanType: PadlocScanCodeType!, scanData: String!) in
     // Do Something   
}
```

Error I keep getting is: Cannot assign value of type 'PadlockScanCodeType!, String!) -> {}' to type 'PadlocScanScanCallback'

Comment: command click `scanCallback`, then `PadlocScanScanCallback`, and it'll show you the Swift type that it's imported as.

Comment: Cool trick...but it gives me a big question mark.

Comment: If the symbol is available, command clicking it should always be able to show you its declaration. Do you get a `?` for `scanCallback` or `PadlocScanScanCallback`?

Comment: scanCallback takes me to the header file in the framework.  PadlocScanScanCallback displays the `?`